# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError has unexpected e_machine: 40

Tags: java, android, epson

I am trying to use the ePOS-Print SDK for Android.

It works fine on ARM Devices. Just not on x86 Devices.

Is the Library only working on ARM Devices or is there a way to make it work on x86 Devices?

```
04-17 09:11:53.390 10989-12211/at.test.test E/art: dlopen("/data/app/test.test-2/lib/x86/libeposprint.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: "/data/app/at.test.test-2/lib/x86/libeposprint.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40

Process: at.calyx.calyxpos, PID: 10989
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/at.test.test/lib/x86/libeposprint.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:371)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989)
at com.epson.eposprint.Builder.<clinit>(Builder.java:17)
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a very similar error by trying to run an ARM app on Android x86. I was able to bypass it by installing `libhoudini`:

1. On Android: `Settings -> Apps Compatibility -> Enable Native Bridge`
2. Start Terminal Emulator (or press `Alt-F1`)
3. Login as root: `su -`
4. Run 

   `cd ~
   /system/bin/enable_nativebridge`
5. Verify success by inspecting logs: `logcat -T 10`
6. Reboot and re-install your ARM apps

[More details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634762/how-to-install-libhoudini-on-a-custom-android-x86-rig)

Comment: this saves my day. on android x86 9.0, the menu for configuring **Enable Native Bridge** is under **Android x86 Options**.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you

Put in gradle.properties this line

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true;
```

and in app/build.gradle this line in defaultConfig field

```
   ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a","x86"
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had to create a gradle.properties file. But it doesnt change anything. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: no need to  create gradle.properties if you are using androd studio. Its already exists in project structure

Comment: sure what part do you want me to post?

Comment: @Reena not working for me still can't find .so file with System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg"); iknw every thing is correct but it's device architecture problem

Answer (score 1):

I think you need build "libeposprint.so" file for x86.

Comment: how to do it. plz help?